# Filter out list of dictionary by value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Is there any way to filter out a list of dictionaries by using the value?

The current implementation is this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> queue = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
//Some code here
queue = queue.Where(x => (string)x[DictionaryKey] != "some Value Here").ToList();
```

But this does not seem to return the filtered list according to the value passed.

Comment: do a google search on how to filter a Dictionary using a lambda expression

Comment: your condition is not correct, queue.Where(x => x.Value != "some Value Her")

Comment: `var filterred = queue.Where(x => x.Where(val => val.Key != "some Value Her")).ToList();` would work.

Comment: Try following : queue = queue.Where(x => x.AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.ToString() == "some Value Here").Count() == 0).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter dictionary, use the following condition, x is a dictionary where you're only filtering the pairs that doesn't have specified value.

```
queue.Where(x => !x.ContainsValue("some Value Her"))
```

Comment: @bampie x is the pair of key and value here so you can use x.Key or x.Value

Comment: Oh sorry thanks @AntonínLejsek I just discovered now, I will update the answer

Comment: Marked this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
queue = queue.Where(x => !x.ContainsValue("some value here")).ToList();
```

It will return all Dictionary objects in the list where there is no value of "some value here".

Answer (score 0):

you could always do it the long way

```
Foreach(Dictionary item in queue){
    if(item.Keys.Contains("value")){
        queue.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

would probably work